# Don't load xml data to list when publishing by Flash CS 5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I build a flash video player which works fine when exported to swf. However when I publish it (F12) does not loading the xml file. As a result video player stuck to frame 2 (where presented a List with video titles and with click on title plays the specific video). The xml link does not ends to .xml. Here is my code about xml loading. I try to change the Flash Player from 10.2 to 9 but I have the same problem.In addition some buttons in frame 2 does not works I suppose because of "Stuck" from xml loading.( Work fine when exported in swf!)

Flash Player version: 10.2, Actionscript:3.0, Flash Professional CS 5.5, fps:24, size: 850px(w)x480px(h). Code from FRAME 2 . Thanks for your time guys.

```
Security.allowDomain( "*" );
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.controls.Label;


var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.olympiacos.org/feeds/videos")
loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError)
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError)
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHTTPStatus2)    
function onIOError(evt:IOErrorEvent){
    trace("IOError: "+evt.text);
}
function onHTTPStatus2(evt:HTTPStatusEvent){
    trace("HTTPStatus: "+evt.status);
}
function onSecurityError(evt:SecurityErrorEvent){
    trace("SecurityError: "+evt.text);
}
function handleComplete(event:Event):void
{
try
{
    var rawXML:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
    trace(rawXML);
    var list:XMLList = rawXML.channel.item;
    for (var i:uint=0; i<list.length(); i++)
    {
        t_text.text = list.title.text()[i];
        var data1:String = (list[i].description);
        var srcRegExp:RegExp = /src="(.*?)"/;
        var data2:String = srcRegExp.exec(data1)[1];
        var lwr = data2.search(/1_/i);
        var her = lwr + 10;
        var data3 = data2.substring(lwr,her);
        trace("Entry Id"+i+": "+data3);
        List1.addItem({label:list.title.text()[i],data:data3});
    }
}
catch (e:TypeError)
{
    //Could not convert the data, probavlu because
    //because is not formated correctly
    trace("Could not parse the XML");
    trace(e.message);
}
}

List1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, itemChange);
openbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, opentween);
closebtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closetween);
closebtn.visible=true;
openbtn.visible=false;

function itemChange(e:Event):void
{
if ( currentFrame == 2)
{
    trace("Video selected");
    gotoAndPlay(3);
}
t_text.text = List1.selectedItem.label;
var videoslcd = List1.selectedItem.data;

}

stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what;s your publishing setting regarding playback security? Should be "Access network only"

[image: FlashProfessional Publishing Settings]

Comment: Adrian I change the local playback security to access network only but still continues xml List not loaded. With this change of playback security the buttons on Frame2 when publishing is fine now!!

Comment: Something is strange. I know you say you need no extension and should work, but have you gave it a try with a .xml extension as well?

Comment: Well I change xml extension with (xml file downloaded and stored in hosting file), but the problem excist.!!!

Comment: can you have some sort of external insterface js call so you can prompt an alert with the errors in the case of TypeError, onIOError, or onSecurityError ?

Comment: One more thing: are you testing by opening the swf, or the html containing the swf ?

Comment: I test it in three different ways. First, swf was published in chrome with html of flash pro (by pushing f12 button). Second, I upload swf to file hosting and run it(xml file is not in the same file).And final I embed in my blog. The problem loading-read xml excist. I read before 5 min about cross domain files that may not be allowed by flash. (   http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html#main_allowDomain ).If I found something I will post it. Thx Adrian :)

Comment: indeed it may be a crossdomain.xml security issue, this is why I asked you to "alert" any possible error message. only knowing the cause will help you fix the issue.

Comment: Welll Adrian I create a .php file, and I put it on file hosting.The .php code is :<?php

$xmlData=file_get_contents($_GET['url'], FILE_TEXT);
echo ($xmlData);
?>

Comment: I change and main code at section of loader:  var path:String = "http://olympiacos-blog.webs.com/feed.php?url=http://www.olympiacos.org/feeds/videos&cacheBreaker="+int(Math.random()*9999999);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loading);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);

Comment: loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHTTPStatus2);
loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(path)
loader.load(req);

Comment: In addition I change the code in loading of xml and output of flash pro was: openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
100
HTTPStatus: 200
completeHandler: <?php

$xmlData=file_get_contents($_GET['url'], FILE_TEXT);

echo ($xmlData);

?>


The answer is undefined

Comment: I have traced the percent of loading (100) and Httpstatus which gave me 200! (?) (100 HTTPStatus: 200)